# node.js script fails to GET static files

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a basic HTML index.html with a handful of containers, and I add **bootstrap** and **font awesome** folders to the `<head>` section of the file. 
Such as:

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, I wrote a `web.js` script to first initialize the server and then add those folders containing static files, in this way:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var buf = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send(buf.toString());
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bootstrap'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/font-awesome'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

However when I go to `http://localhost:8080` I get 404 errors from GET commands trying to obtain `bootstrap.css`, etc. Any help? I tried different scripts obtained from stackoverflow  but I can't seem to get it right.
thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By initializing `express.static` in this way, you are telling it to look in those folders off of the root for the any requested files.

If you were to remove the paths:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Your static assets will likely be found.  However, you are asking for headaches down the road as any duplicate filenames will result in the first being returned.

Instead, you might want to place all of your static assets under a single directory or add a different path parameter to your `app.use` statements to keep things better organized.

File layout:

```
public
 |-- bootstrap
 |-- font-awesome
```

Corresponding app.use statement (and remove the .. from your html paths):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
```

or multiple static middleware (and remove the .. from your html paths):

```
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/bootstrap')));
app.use('/font-awesome', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/font-awesome')));
```

HTML changes for either of the above:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: that was a great explanation! And nice suggestion using `public/` as well, makes it more easily organized and explicit in the `<head>`. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try in html:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In node app:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets')));
app.use('/bootstrap', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/bootstrap')));
app.use('/font-awesome', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/font-awesome')));
```

Comment: thank you very much! That worked perfectly too, I missed that first parameter of `use()` function. great!